# Recording Script in LoadRunner11.50 with IE9 using 'Ajax -Click and script' Protocol Getting Error "IE has been stop working"

Tags: loadrunner

I am facing problem in bellow scenario : 
Using - Windows 7 (64bit), IE9, LR 11.50, and 'Ajax -Click and script' Protocol.

Recording below scenario
1) Navigate to my application![alt text][1]
2) logged in with admin credential
3) click on a link 
while recording clicking on any link, getting a popup error 'Internet Explorer has stopped working' Please find the error attachment.

Same scenario doing manually that also working fine.

But Same scenarios Logged in as different credential than working fine ..... why its happening with admin credential ?

Can any one Please help me what exactly problem is : 
1) is it Recording setting issue 
2) IE setting issue
3) Application issue
4) or else

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues in play

- See release notes regarding recording in 64 bit environments.  VUGEN is a 32 bit product.
- For 11.0 and later the recommended path is either TruClient (if you need Ajax support) or HTTP.   Click and Script variants are there for historical purposes but the recommended path is higher or lower in the OSI model